# Uniform Convergence of $\frac{n}{x}\sin\frac{x}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is the series of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{x}\sin\frac{x}{n}$ uniformly convergent on $(0,2)$?

Roughly, I think $\sin\frac{x}{n}$ ~ $\frac{x}{n}$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$. So $f_n(x)\rightarrow 1$.

Any idea how to prove this?

Comment: That gives you pointwise convergence to $1$ (you're basically doing the argument that $\sin(x)/x \to 1$ as $x\to 0$). So if there was a uniform limit, it would also be $1$. Now you can check if $1$ is indeed a uniform limit using the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the study of
$$
1-\frac nx\sin\frac xn
$$on $(0,2)$.

It is $F(\frac xn)$ where $F(x) = 1-\frac 1x\sin x$.
As $\lim_0 F = 0$, for each $\epsilon>0$ one can find $r>0$ such as
$$
|x|<r\Rightarrow |F(x)|<\epsilon
$$
then taking $N>\frac 2r$,$$n\ge N \ \ \&\ \ 0<x<2\Rightarrow \frac xn<\frac 2N<r$$ and
$$ \left|1-\frac nx\sin\frac xn\right| = \left|F\left(\frac xn\right)\right| < \epsilon$$
that is the uniform convergence.